# Show the mechanism of the Pinacol-Pinacolone Rearrangement reaction

Tags: reaction-mechanism, alcohols, rearrangements

> [image]

In the reactant, due to $\ce{H+}$ ion, a positive charge will be created by removing water in place of the rightmost $-\ce{OH}$.

But then how will it give such a product. I cant see any way to make the cyclic pentane first.

There would be a Pinacol-Pinacolone Rearrangement but how ?